# Function only on click of the exact class and data-id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two elements both with the same class `.one`. Click this button and show class `.A`.
One of those elements also has a data-id of `two`. Click this button and show class `.B`.

But, as the second "button" also has the class `.one` it's showing both `.A` and `.B`.

How can I say perform this function/ show `.B` **only** if button has `.one and .two`?

https://jsfiddle.net/tdo6cz7p/

```js
$('.one').on('click', function() {
  $('.A').show();
});
$("[data-id='two'].one").on('click', function() {
  $('.B').show();
});
```

```css
.one {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid black
}

.A,
.B {
  display: none;
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">one</div>
<div data-id="two" class="one">two one</div>


<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector like this:

```js
$('.one:not([data-id="two"])').on('click', function() {
  $('.A').show();
});
$("[data-id='two'].one").on('click', function() {
  $('.B').show();
});
```

```css
.one {width: 50px;margin: 10px;padding: 10px 0;text-align: center;outline: 1px solid black}

.A, .B {display: none;background: yellow;width: 50px;margin: 10px;padding: 10px 0;text-align: center;outline: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">one</div>
<div data-id="two" class="one">two one</div>


<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to accept one or the other when any `$('.one')` is clicked:

```
$('.one').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).data('id')) {
    $('.B').show();
  } else {
    $('.A').show();
  }
});
```

```js
if ($(this).data('id')) {...
// if the `data-id` has a value ex. "2", then it is true
```

```js
$('.one').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).data('id')) {
    $('.B').show();
  } else {
    $('.A').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.one {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid black
}

.A,
.B {
  display: none;
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">one</div>
<div data-id="two" class="one">two one</div>


<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
```

Comment: should abosolutely use the this.id statement

Comment: Would this affect other data-id's?

Comment: Only if there's another `.one` with `data-id="${some value}"`. If so, you can specify by `if ($(this).data('id') === '2') {...`

Answer (score 1):

JQuery selector equals to `querySelectorAll`, while `querySelector` selects only the first element it finds:

```js
document.querySelector(".one").onclick = function() {
  $('.A').show();
}
$("[data-id='two'].one").on('click', function() {
  $('.B').show();
});
```

```css
.one {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid black
}

.A,
.B {
  display: none;
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">one</div>
<div data-id="two" class="one">two one</div>


<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
```